# Java IO: Memory/Performance issue when reading “last lines” of files using bufferedReader

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, io, bufferedreader

I have two simple sample files with the following data structure:
person.csv

```
0|John
1|Maria
2|Anne
```

and

item.csv

```
0|car|blue
0|bycicle|red
1|phone|gold
2|purse|black
2|book|black
```

I need to gather all the related lines (lines with the same identity, in this example the integer 0, 1 or 2) of all files and do something (irrelevant to this question) with them after gathering them. 
The first group of related lines (list of strings) should look like this:

```
0|John
0|car|blue
0|bycicle|red
```

The second group of related lines:

```
1|Maria
1|phone|gold
```

etc.

The actual files are about 5 to 10gb each file. The files are sorted on the first column and the file with the smallest id gets opened for reading first. Memory is a restricting factor (can’t read the whole file in memory). With that in mind I wrote the following code that seems to work fine for reading most of the lines and then grouping them how I want… however, the last part (in my code I set a logging count on 250.000 groups) takes significantly longer and memory usages spikes.

**Main**

```
public class Main {

    private static int groupCount = 0;
    private static int totalGroupCount = 0;
    private static long start = 0;
    private static int lineCount;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroupedReader groupedReader = new GroupedReader();
        groupedReader.orderReadersOnSmallestId();
        long fullStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lineCount = 0;
        while (groupedReader.hasNext()) {
            groupCount++;
            List<String> relatedLines = groupedReader.readNextGroup();
            for (String line : relatedLines) {
                lineCount++;
            }
            totalGroupCount++;
            if (groupCount == 250_000) {
                System.out.println("Building " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(groupCount) + " groups took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1e3 + " sec");
                groupCount = 0;
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Building " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(groupCount) + " groups took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1e3 + " sec");
        System.out.println(String.format("Building [ %s ] groups from [ %s ] lines took %s seconds", NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(totalGroupCount), NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(lineCount), (System.currentTimeMillis() - fullStart) / 1e3));
        System.out.println("all done!");
    }
}
```

**GroupedReader** ...ommited some methods

```
public class GroupedReader {

    private static final String DELIMITER = "|";
    private static final String INPUT_DIR = "src/main/resources/";

    private boolean EndOfFile = true;
    private List<BufferedReader> sortedReaders;
    private TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> cachedLines;
    private List<String> relatedLines;
    private int previousIdentifier;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (sortedReaders.isEmpty()) ? false : true;
    }

    public List<String> readNextGroup() {
        updateCache();
        EndOfFile = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedReaders.size(); i++) {
            List<String> currentLines = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                BufferedReader br = sortedReaders.get(i);
                for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                    int firstDelimiterIndex = StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line, DELIMITER, 1);
                    int currentIdentifier = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, firstDelimiterIndex));
                    if (previousIdentifier == -1) {
                        // first iteration
                        previousIdentifier = currentIdentifier;
                        relatedLines.add(i + DELIMITER + line);
                        continue;
                    } else if (currentIdentifier > previousIdentifier) {
                        // next identifier, so put the lines in the cache
                        currentLines.add(i + DELIMITER + line);
                        if (cachedLines.get(currentIdentifier) != null) {
                            List<String> local = cachedLines.get(currentIdentifier);
                            local.add(i + DELIMITER + line);
                        } else {
                            cachedLines.put(currentIdentifier, currentLines);
                        }
                        EndOfFile = false;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        // same identifier
                        relatedLines.add(i + DELIMITER + line);
                    }
                }
                if (EndOfFile) {
                    // is this close needed?
                    br.close();
                    sortedReaders.remove(br);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (cachedLines.isEmpty()) cachedLines = null;
        return relatedLines;
    }

    private void updateCache() {
        if (cachedLines != null) {
            previousIdentifier = cachedLines.firstKey();
            relatedLines = cachedLines.get(cachedLines.firstKey());
            cachedLines.remove(cachedLines.firstKey());
        } else {
            previousIdentifier = -1;
            relatedLines = new ArrayList<>();
            cachedLines = new TreeMap<>();
            // root of all evil...?
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried “playing”  around with explicitly closing readers and calling garbage collector, but I can’t spot the actual flaw in the code I wrote.

**Question:**
What is causing the slowdown of the read near the end of the file?

**Simple syso log:**

```
Building 250,000 groups took 0.394 sec
Building 250,000 groups took 0.261 sec
Building 250,000 groups took 0.289 sec
...
Building 250,000 groups took 0.281 sec
Building 250,000 groups took 0.314 sec
Building 211,661 groups took 10.829 sec
Building [ 9,961,661 ] groups from [ 31,991,125 ] lines took 21.016 seconds
all done!
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.gc()` is a request but not guarantee that GC will take place.

If you want a quick way to see where time is being spent add more logging at more points in the code and reduce the groupCount to a smaller amount to see a better break down of time (10000?).

If you want to properly profile and get a better understanding then use the tools that come with the JDK, either the older [visualvm](https://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html) or the new [mission control](http://blog.takipi.com/oracle-java-mission-control-the-ultimate-guide/).

Both can be found in the bin folder in your JDK installation.

Comment: The `System.gc()` was/is a bit of experimental code and I know that I should try to avoid using it. I will try out the profiling options, however I can't accept your answer for it is not a direct answer to my question.

Comment: If you want a concrete answer you would need to post the full Java classes and a full dump of your data files. If this is a true idiosyncrasy it may not be found with what has been provided. Best of luck with the tools!